# How do I initialize the lattice/grid in a Potts Model?

Tags: simulations, ising-model

I am studying the following:

- [Cellular Potts Model Tutorial](https://artistoo.net/explorables/Explorable-CPM.html)

However, either this doesn't say anything about the grid/lattice initialization, or I failed to find any indication.

How do I initialize the lattice/grid in a Potts Model?

I.e., how do I assign initial pixel values before running the Monte Carlo loop?

Comment: It would appear to me at least that you randomly assign pixels and then let the system evolve according to the model.

Comment: Cross-posted on MatterModeling.SE https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9552/671 by a user of the same name.